# Wrapper method for SqlClient

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sqlclient

I have the following wrapper method that works nicely whenever I need to execute a stored procedure using `SqlDataReader`.

I want to now modify it a bit so that it handles two more scenarios:

1. I will simply call `ExecuteNonQuery()`
2. I will call `ExecuteNonQuery()` but will also read value of an input/output parameter. This parameter could be any one of the input parameters and its type could be a GUID, `int`, `DateTime` or a string.

How do I modify this method so that I can use it in these two scenarios as well?

```
public static void ExecuteStoredProc(string procedureName, Action<SqlCommand> setParametersAction, Action<SqlDataReader> handleReaderAction)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procedureName, conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        if (setParametersAction != null)
            setParametersAction(cmd);

        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (handleReaderAction != null)
        {
            handleReaderAction(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bad path, I suggest to use an ORM and dump your own do-it-all methods

Comment: I've used helper methods like this a lot -- I suggest you create 3 functions for your 3 different use cases.

Comment: Yeah, why not just overload the method?

Comment: I already overloaded it. Just wanted to get some ideas to see if there was a nice an easy way to modify this method further. Thank you all.